# Spotify API to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

May be a simple question, but I am trying to use Spotify's API which is documented in Objective C but I have been working on it in Swift as far as I can.

**@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray *genres**
is one of their API protocols for the SPTartist class, however; I can't figure out how to use it in a working manner in swift.

Here is example code of something I have gotten to work.

```
    func updateTrackLength(){
    if player?.currentTrackMetadata == nil {
        trackLength.text = ""
        return
    }
    let length = player?.currentTrackMetadata[SPTAudioStreamingMetadataTrackDuration] as Int
    let convert = length / 60
    let remainder = length % 60
    var newlength = String(convert)
    var newRemainder = String(remainder)


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.trackLength.text = "Track length: " + newlength + " Minutes " + newRemainder + " Seconds"
    })
}
```

This uses the currentTrackMetaData and whatever SPT protocol to track the string output. When I try using SPTArtistGenres or SPTArtistGenre in place of SPTAudioStreamingMetaDataTrackDuration, it does not work.
To specify my question, I want to use the currentTrackMetaData to call the genres property up above. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has absolutely nothing to do with Swift - if you tried to do what you're doing in Objective-C it'd fail as well.

The player's `currentTrackMetadata` dictionary returns bare URLs - if you just `println()` the response to `player.currentTrackMetadata`, you'll see that it contains nothing but URLs.

The `genres` property is on the `SPTArtist` class.  To convert your bare URL into an `SPTArtist`, use the `SPTRequest` class (specifically, the `requestItemAtURI` method). Once you have an `SPTArtist` object, you'll be able to get all the metadata you need from it, including genres.

Please see the documentation shipped with the library for details. In addition, the Simple Player demo app included with the SDK does a similar thing.